# How to use options in wget when downloading with list?

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm using wget to download files and I prepared a list of links, now I have to use some options on every link in the list like I have to delete files less than 30 KB, Have to rename every file according to previous link etc. But I don't want to use a bash script, Is there a way to do it?

List to Download:

```
http://example.com/blah?blah --delete-after
http://example.com/download -O mynewfilename
...
```

Comment: So you have a set of options applied to every link, or every link has its own set of options?

Comment: Every link has its own set of options.
But set of options for every link can also work.

Comment: `http://example.com/blah?blah --delete-after`
`http://example.com/download -O mynewfilename`
`...`

Comment: [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: Add more details, concrete examples to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a set of arguments per line for a command in a file, you can use `xargs` to run the command with them. From [`man xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
--arg-file=file
-a file
      Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this
      option,  stdin  remains  unchanged  when   commands   are   run.
      Otherwise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.


-L max-lines
      Use at most max-lines nonblank input  lines  per  command  line.
      Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on
      the next input line.  Implies -x.
```

Example file (`foo`):

```
a b c
d e
f g h
```

So:

```
$ xargs -a foo echo    
a b c d e f g h
$ xargs -L1 -a foo echo
a b c
d e
f g h
```

So, you can probably do:

```
xargs -L1 -a input.txt wget
```